# SQL Selecting Data from 2 columns and inserting into view if it is not NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, view, null

I have a view extracting data from multiple tables. In one of the view's columns I need to insert an account code, this account code can be found under credit or debit column in one of the tables. If there an account code in the debit column there wont be in the credit column and vice versa. Basically I need to insert the account code if it is found in either columns.

I cant change the view columns because of a UNION.

Maybe I am searching for this information using the wrong keywords but I cant seem to find what I need.

Thanks.

Updated with Query

```
    SELECT
DET_YEAR as [Year],
DET_PERIODNUMBR as [Period],
DET_TYPE AS [Type],
'' AS [Status],
DET_Date AS [Tran Date],
'' AS [Supplier],
'' AS [Supplier Name],
DET_DESCRIPTION as [Description],
DET_DIMENSION3 AS [Department],
'' as [Entry Type],
'' as [Detail],
DET_GROSS as [Value],
DET_COSTHEADER as [Project Code],
CH_NAME as [Project Name], 
DET_COSTCENTRE AS [Project Cost Centre],
'' AS [Analysis Code],
'' AS [Analysis Name],
'' AS [Nominal Code],
'' AS [Account Name],
DET_NOMINALDR as [DebitNominal],
DET_NOMINALCR AS [CreditNominal],
NNAME as [Dr/CrNominalName], 
'' AS POH_ORDER_NUMBR,
DET_BATCH_REF


FROM SL_PL_NL_DETAIL WITH (NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN CST_COSTHEADER WITH (NOLOCK) ON DET_COSTHEADER = CH_CODE
LEFT JOIN CST_COSTCENTRE WITH (NOLOCK) ON DET_COSTCENTRE = CC_CODE AND DET_COSTHEADER = CC_COPYHEADER
INNER JOIN NL_ACCOUNTS WITH (NOLOCK) ON (DET_NOMINALDR = NCODE OR DET_NOMINALCR = NCODE)

WHERE DET_TYPE IN ('JNL', 'VJL') AND DET_BATCH_FLAG = 0 AND DET_YEAR IN ('C', 'N'))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Can you show us the table structures - or a relevant subset of columns if they're large - and what you've tried?

Comment: I am using MSSQL

Comment: Show us some base table sample data, the view definition, and the current and wanted result.

Comment: I need to put DET_NOMINALDR or DET_NOMINALCR into Nominal Code, current results is spread over 2 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a CASE statement - without seeing your tables I'm only guessing but you could do something like this:

```
SELECT ....,
    CASE WHEN credit IS NOT NULL THEN credit ELSE debit END AS account_code,
    -- (etc)
```

Of course, you can use any other condition as required if the columns are not null.

Comment: CASE WHEN DET_NOMINALDR IS NOT NULL THEN DET_NOMINALDR ELSE DET_NOMINALCR END AS [Nominal Code], is not working as well same issue as the other suggestion.

Comment: Can the CR and DR columns be null? If not, then you'll need to test them using some other condition. What appears in them if the account code you want isn't there?

Comment: I might have a problem because they are in string format such as '1222-1020'

Comment: That's fine, but what appears in either column when the account code **is not** there? - for example, when the account code is in the CR column, what is in the DR column?

Comment: If there is an account in CR the DR iis "blank" or NULL

Comment: If it's NULL, then CASE ... IS NOT NULL should work.... what happened when you tried it?

Comment: I have added a picture in the question

Comment: What is in the empty columns? Are they actually NULL, or are they just zero-length strings? Those are two very different things. You haven't shown your table definitions - are they NOT NULL?

Comment: They are 0 length strings. I have also added an image of what I think you are referring to when saying definitions.

Comment: Well then, you need to change the CASE statement to something like CASE WHEN credit <> '' THEN credit ELSE debit END

Comment: This worked,

CASE WHEN LEN(DET_NOMINALDR)>0 THEN DET_NOMINALDR ELSE DET_NOMINALCR END AS [Nominal Code]

Comment: Glad you're sorted. I think you need to read up on NULL - I get the feeling it's not what you think it is. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding correctly then, you can use `ISNULL` or `COALESCE` as following

```
ISNULL(a.column, b.column)
OR
COALESCE(a.column, b.column....)  
--We can define multiple columns but it will return first NOT NULL value
```

Check out this example:

```
CREATE TABLE #testOne(id int identity(1,1), 
    accountDebit varchar(50), accountCredit varchar(50))

insert into #testOne values
(null, '1222-1020')

select * from #testOne

id  accountDebit    accountCredit
1   NULL            1222-1020

select id, 
    isnull(accountDebit, accountCredit) AS account_code 
from #testOne
```

OUTPUT

```
id  account_code
1   1222-1020
```

Comment: ISNULL(DET_NOMINALDR, DET_NOMINALCR) AS [Nominal Code] is not working only the debit is being added to the Nominal Code

Comment: what value is there in debit column ? if there is even 0 then you have to use as ISNULL(NULLIF(debit,0),NULLIF(credit,0)) or check for blank ISNULL(NULLIF(debit,''),NULLIF(credit,''))

Comment: I might have a problem because they are in string format such as '1222-1020'

Comment: I have updated my answer with example, please have a look and try to do accordingly. If your column containing 0 or blank then check for that with `NULLIF`.